# Sharepoint 2010 FBA Enable peopele picker from intranet to select asp.net membership users from internet site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, asp.net-membership, claims-based-identity, fba

I have got two sites:

1) intranet company.local (claimed ad)

2) internet company.com ( extended on 1) ) forms (asp.net membership)

I have got this in web.configs

OkSMP2 is name of asp.net membership provider

At 1) I see only All Users, Sharepoint Groups, AD service. There is no FormsAuth :(

Any ideas?

Comment: It is required for setting visibility for asp.net users in shared documents library

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blogpost - and make sure that you follow the steps correctly - http://jopx.blogspot.com/2010/09/form-based-authentication-in-sharepoint.html